# Loading a dataset - Can I access the record set to see the results before the load has returned?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way during the load of an ADOQuery that I can - perhaps with some kind of callback event or something - get the values of a record as they are being loaded into the Dataset? Without having to wait until the load is finished before I loop the recordset to do what I want to do?

Comment: No. That is not what a TQuery is designed for. It is meant to give the complete result of a SQL statement. You would need to implement some sort of threading TQuery to get that behavior.

Comment: @Sherlock70:  I'm not sure that's correct.  TAdoQuery <> TQuery and has additional capabilities including async fetch (so results can be returned before the query completes) and also see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09a6060a-1f72-4438-a3b2-209c240ee4d6/fastfirstrow?forum=transactsql.

Comment: I have my own objectlist I want to populate with the results.  With that being said, for larger datasets, I have that performance penalty of having to loop again through the whole dataset and populate my own structure.  I'm trying to find a way I can reduce this as much as I can.

Comment: I think looping over the dataset should be very fast compared to actually querying the data. If it's slow, it would probably be because of data aware controls linked to the dataset (think a DBGrid that updates its active row). This can be optimized largely by calling DisableControls on the dataset before looping. Alternatively, you could link up a clientdataset to the dataset and work from there. I think (but don't know exactly) that traversing a clientdataset is way faster than an ADODataset.

Comment: @GolezTrol Ok, let me elaborate.  It's not just looping it, but for every record I have to construct an object which consists of the fields of the dataset and its values.  Doing that for a large dataset is what makes up my permance penalty.  So looking at threaded methods could help, but ideally I'd like to tap into the dataset load to do it in one operation.  For datasets thats not massive, maybe a thousand or so, its not that bigger deal.  But I want the whole thing to be smart as well

Comment: But just doing the work somewhere in-between fetching of dataset rows will not magically make the task consume no time, instead of having Operation A that takes A amount of time and Operation B that takes B amount of time (and small overhead for iterating a dataset) you will have an Operation C that will take A + B amount of time.

Comment: Have you tried what @MartynA proposed ?. ExecuteOptions = [eoAsyncFetchNonBlocking] and run your code on the OnFetchProgress event.

Comment: @MarcGuillot, No I haven't and it sounds promising.  I haven't had the time to continue with the project to test this out, but it sounds like it could work